# parse year and month from a string SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, parsing, time, google-bigquery

I have a column `Time` in the BigQuery table. The data type is STRING. The data looks like this: `2020-10-15-03:15:40`. I need to parse year and month. The desired output is: `2020-10`. I have tried:

```
SELECT
    date(parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%T', Time)) as Date
FROM `bigquery_table`
```

Error message: `failed to parse a string "2020-10-15-03:15:40"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using string operations?

```
select substring(time, 1, 4) as year,
       substring(time, 6, 2) as month
```

If this were any sort of date/time data type, you can use `extract()`:

```
select extract(year from time) as year,
       extract(month from time) as month
```

I strongly encourage you to use the correct data types for your values.  But if you or your DBA has chosen not to follow this simple best practice, then you can just use string operations.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select format_datetime('%Y-%m', parse_datetime('%F-%T', time)) as year_month   
from `bigquery_table`
```

if to apply it to sample data from your question    -  output is

[image]